# How do I use a RubyGem I made in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently developed a simple RubyGem and deployed it to RubyGems.org. How do I use this RubyGem within a Rails application? Here is the code to the Gem

```
 module Gem1
     class Message
         def self.gem?
  puts "Hi This is a RubyGem"
       end
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the gem in your Gemfile and do a bundle install.
Typically can be done

```
gem 'nokogiri'
```

in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

once the gem is installed you can access it across your application

Comment: Thanks but how do I actually display  the message in the gem in a view in a Rails application?

Comment: Gem1::Message.gem?  that will allow you to access and print the output of gem? method

Wondering why you used ? when you are validating anything.